# overlay image mask equivalent in CV2

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib

I want to plot two images on top of each other. In matplotlib this is easily done:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
plt.imshow(mask, cmap="jet", alpha = 0.3)
plt.show()
```

what is the equivalent in cv2?.

Comment: can you show your code for `addweighted` ?

Comment: @SimonChemnitz-Thomsen Closing this question as a duplicate